# Changing font in Android making the app to crash?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the font of a textview inside of android.

Here is the code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(font);
```

And i put the font in `src/main/assets/fonts` folder.

But when I try to run the app (On emulator) it crashes. Why is that?

EDIT: here is my error message I get.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.asus.wetr, PID: 3973
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asus.wetr/com.asus.wetr.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Roboto-Thin.TTF
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Roboto-Thin.TTF
                  at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)
                  at com.asus.wetr.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Application terminated.
```

EDIT2: here is my activity.xml as requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.asus.wetr.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background_color">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="238dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textColor="#FFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Provide the actual crash dump / error.

Comment: Post what errors u are getting!

Comment: Please remove `fonts` directory within `assets` and change path in `createFromAsset` method.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski it still crashed after doing it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure my own problem out. Guys, I wanna thank you all you your inputs. I made a small (I'm a novice at this) error, which screwed everything up.

I put this code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface thisfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(thisfont);
```

before this:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

which will not work (obvious for most of you why) because the layout have not been set up yet. It has to be after. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to pass `TextView` Context to `createFromAsset` method of `TypeFace` class

Use:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext()
            .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I did but now I get this error: ´java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.widget.TextView.getContext()' on a null object reference´, any ideas?

Comment: post your activity.xml please

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami Why would it solve the problem? Please elaborate on your solution.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami `textView.getContext()` and `this` both refer to the enclosing Activity, so it shouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Carlton Jr, your exception is Font asset not found fonts/Roboto-Thin.TTF so you should make sure about your font and it's directory.

Comment: It is in the right directory, I also tried different fonts, still wouldnt work.

Comment: @Hi I'm Frogatto, i just guess maybe text view content should set by this way but now i get OP has problem with font! they are both correct i mean passing textview content or without passing it. but they're seperate ways

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami So I've just wondered who has upvoted your answer!

Comment: in this situations you should do refresh project or clean project or even build project. if everything is ok, it seems IDE don't recognized that file or folder.

Comment: @Hi I'm Frogatto, I don't know who but he/she wasn't mistake, this is a correct way to change font of textview in android.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhatami No, `textView.getContext() == this`. So, your answer wouldn't change anything.

Comment: i said both are correct ways. maybe they're same from lower level of architect.. if you've better answer for OP question i'd be happy!

Comment: @CarltonJr. You can use the android:typeface attribute in textview in your activity.xml to change it! Like android:typeface="sans" -goodluck!

Comment: @CarltonJr, also check Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Roboto-Thin.ttf"); OR Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");

Answer (score 1):

Looking into stacktrace:

> Font asset not found fonts/Roboto-Thin.TTF

It looks like your file name is different. Even **file extension** case matters. So, are you sure that file name is exactly the same, together with extension case?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure, I even right clicked on the font (In Android Studio project navigation) and copied reference. I also did as you said, I removed the fonts directory and changes it to "Roboto-Thin.ttf" in the createFromAsset() method. Also tried with different fonts and it still didn't work. I don't know what to try next? :(